# RFID + Android --> where do I start?

Tags: java, android, python, rfid

I've heard that the Google Nexus S has RFID capabilities. I'd like to start learning about RFID and programmatically doing things. Where should I start? Good tutorials or code examples are what I'm after. (or hardware if it's not Android I suppose).

Doesn't have to be Android, could be python or java libraries as well. Preference for Android.

I see this as the future, and I want to get in on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a Nexus-S, buy some tags.

Then take a look at the code of the 'Tags' application that comes with android. Play with it, modify it. Write some tags with your own application.

Learn what Ndef is and how you craft your own messages/records. Learn how to use the transceive function to do direct communication to the tags. This will open up a world on it's own (aka you can write-protect tags that are not write protectable by Android itself etc).

All in all that can be done in two weeks. The Android NFC/RFID subsystem is easy to use. Most of the the hard stuff is hidden from you.

Afterwards write your own little application, show it to advertising agencies that do Android apps and get a high payed job. NFC experience is highly sought after at the moment.

Comment: any special type of tags that you would recommend buying? what is used most now in commercial settings - passive or active?